# Python MYSQL Cursor Update Query Not working

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
update = self.__db.execute("UPDATE users SET `pending`=0, `approval_admin`=%s WHERE `id`=%s",(str(self.__user['id']),str(arg)))
```

This query is not working, even though its not throwing any error exception, but the DB is not getting updated at all.
Any possible reason I might be doing it wrong? The cursor is working fine as I executed another SELECT statement just before this line, and it gave right results. 
Is there any need to reset the cursor for consecutive queries?

I am using the package

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Comment: You're probably missing `self.__db.commit()`. I'm not sure why you have the leading double underscore, there shouldn't be a need for name mangling.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked like charm.
The leading underscores are just to denote private variables for the class

Comment: Single underscores denote private variables. Double underscores invoke name mangling. Nothing is truly private in Python.